# Изменение изображения в bin прошивке через Hex

Tags: hex, binary, прошивка

Не получается изменить в файле прошивки регистратора два изображения: logo_on.jpg и logo_off.jpg. Названия вычислил путем разбора прошивки.
Пробовал заменить путем поиска метки начала и конца *.jpg файла в HEX формате и путем поиска инициализации изображений.
[Ссылка на файл firmware.bin](http://dropmefiles.com/6IyCx)

Comment: Редактировался bin файл при помощи Free Hex Editor Neo

Comment: Не получается по какой причине? Вообще, поиском по "FF D8 FF E0" находится более чем достаточно jpg-файлов.

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что при замене тела изображения с началом FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 и концом файла FF D9 устройство не прошивается.

Comment: поиск коллизии в неизвестном алгоритме хэширования — это, пожалуй, покруче постановки диагноза по фотографии. Михаил, как вы думаете, чем вам сможет помочь хоть кто-нибудь в этом секторе галактики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При подмене изображения с меткой начала .jpg файла FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 и конца FF D9, должно было совпадать количество байт в подмененном изображении. Более того, для того чтобы устройство прошилось без ошибки, формат jpg нужно было конвертировать в формат .jfif
Изображение которое изначально использовалось для подмены в бинарном виде было больше, что вызывало смещение адресного пространства.